# How to replace a modify text globally in tree using Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, replace, tags, seo

I'm working on SEO on dad's website. I have many files divided in to destination, underdestination etc.

For example i have these alt tags:

```
 alt="Kefalonia - Skala 1" /></a
 alt="Kefalonia - Skala 2" /></a
 alt="Kefalonia - Skala 3" /></a
 alt="Kefalonia - Skala 4" /></a
```

Word **skala** is always different each file. Word **Kefalonia** is same in all files in destination called **Kefalonia**.

As you can see it ends by **closing a tag** I need insert it front of **closing a tag** new **title** with this structure: **Skala (number 1-4) some text.**

ATM i'm im using **CTRL+D** and edit it file by file for example like this

1. move closing a tag on new line
2. copy alt for new line
3. rename new alt to title
   etc.. It's long and boring.

I thing there must be smarter way to do that. I've found **CTRL+SHIFT+H** where i can replace some text globaly in whole tree. I just i don't know how to use it for my case.

Simply i need this. Where word **Skala** is always different each file.

Easy image what i need

[image: Easy image what i need]

Answer (score 0):

Use the Search Bar `Ctrl+Shift+F`

- search regex for `alt="Kefalonia - (\w+) (\d+)" /></a`
- replace with: `alt="Kefalonia - $1 $2"\n\ttitle="$1 - Some text $2" /></a`

Comment: @user19571523 Where in the question do you talk about `Korfu`, when have you ever seen a closing tag `</a` that contains an attribute